# Unable to Reach Spinnaker on GKE After IAP Configuration

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, spinnaker

I deployed Spinnaker to GKE using hal and confirmed the UI was working locally via port forwarding by *hal deploy connect*.

I then proceeded to implement IAP for public access via protected endpoint.  The authentication workflow appears to behave as expected as I am successfully routed through the corporate login and MFA auth screens.  The Spinnaker "Hello" screen briefly flashes, however, before quickly returning to the following error:

*Service Unavailable The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems.
Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) Server at spinnaker-dev.endpoints.xxxxxxxxxxxx.cloud.goog Port 9000*

I have reviewed the container logs associated with each workload, Gate, Deck, Clouddriver, etc.. with no material results.

Comment: Are you following [this](https://cloud.google.com/docs/ci-cd/spinnaker/spinnaker-for-gcp)? Is Deck still available without IAP?

Comment: I have deployed the GCP Spinnaker as a Service environment a number of times and enabled IAP via the associated scripts.  Each deployment worked as expected.

In this particular environment, I deployed Spinnaker using the docs located at [https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/].  **However**, I leveraged the Spinnaker as a Service scripting to configure IAP.

I disabled IAP via _hal config security authn iap disable_, removed the api and ui override-base-url and ui deployed and connected on localhost:9000.

Comment: I am able to reach the Infrastructure and Application tabs on the Spinnaker console but now received the following error:


Error fetching applications. Check that your gate endpoint is accessible. Further information on troubleshooting this error is available here.

Comment: Based on the Console logs from Chrome, this is a CORS issues.  I am unclear what else needs reverted to get localhost working again.

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8084/credentials?expand=true' from origin 'http://localhost:9000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute